# OpenCV Android Comparing Finger Touch Position to Moments Position

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, touch-event

I have an Android application that uses Native OpenCV Library to track objects in my camera view. I find the position of the objects using moments:

```
Moments moment = moments((Mat) contours[i]);
double area = moment.m00;
object.setXPos(moment.m10 / area);
object.setYPos(moment.m01 / area);
```

What I am trying to implement is a way to see if my finger touch Point is within a distance threshold to the object position. However, Android calculates my finger position based on touch location on screen, whereas the object's position is calculated by moments, which I believe is causing wacky results when I calculate the distance from the touch event to the object location. Is there any way to remedy this, or am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks in advance for your help!

Other possibly useful info:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    double x = event.getX();
    double y = event.getY();
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            //jni function. Converts x and y to Point(x, y) and compares its distance to tracked object locations
            GetTouchedPoint(x, y);
        }
    }

    return false;
}


//Native function: p1 is finger touch location, p2 is object location (found by moments)
int ObjectDetector::distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    int dx = p1.x - p2.x;
    int dy = p1.y - p2.y;
    int distance = sqrt(pow(dx, 2) + pow(dy, 2));
    return distance;
}
```